# Counting recursion in a python program!

Tags: python, recursion, static

I need to count the number of times recursion in a python program. So basically I need a static variable kind of thing (like in C) which can count the number of times the function is called.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Just pass a counter with the recursion

```
def recur(n, count=0):
    if n == 0:
        return "Finished count %s" % count
    return recur(n-1, count+1)
```

Or im sure there is some fancy decorator, Im gonna investigate that now...

Answer (score 20):

Another method using [`global`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#global):

```
>>> def recur(n):
...     global counter
...     counter+=1
...     if n==0:
...         return -1
...     else:
...         return recur(n-1)
... 
>>> counter = 0
>>> recur(100)
-1
>>> print counter
101
>>>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can define a Counter callable class with which you can wrap any function:

```
class Counter(object) :
    def __init__(self, fun) :
        self._fun = fun
        self.counter=0
    def __call__(self,*args, **kwargs) :
        self.counter += 1
        return self._fun(*args, **kwargs)

def recur(n) :
    print 'recur',n
    if n>0 :
        return recur(n-1)
    return 0

recur = Counter(recur)

recur(5)

print '# of times recur has been called =', recur.counter
```

The advantage here being that you can use it for any function, without having to modify it's signature.

**EDIT**: Thanks to @Tom Zych for spotting a bug. The `recur` name has to be masked by the callable class instance for this to work. More info on decorators here:

http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Counting_function_calls

Comment: Nice idea, but it outputs `1` for me. Isn't it only the first call that goes through `Counter`? I don't see a way to make the recursive calls go through `Counter` without the wrapped function being aware of it.

Comment: @Tom Zych Thanks for spotting that! I've fixed it now.

Comment: Oh, of course. Shadow the function name. Very nice.

Comment: Or rather, reassign the function name.

Answer (score 5):

One way would be to use a `list` containing one element that keeps a count of how many times the function was entered.

```
>>> counter=[0]
>>> def recur(n):
...     counter[0]+=1
...     if n==0:
...             return -1
...     else:
...             return recur(n-1)
... 
>>> recur(100)
-1
>>> print counter[0]
101
```

Comment: what is the benefit of having `list` instead of a variable?

Comment: @shaikmoeed I think so that you don't have to mess around with declaring a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def func(n, count=0):
...     if n==0:
...             return count
...     else:
...             return func(n-1, count+1)
... 
>>> func(100)
100
```