# How to delete a "node" which is passed to a method in a single linked list using Python

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I want to implement 5 ways of deleting a node in a single linked list.

1. Delete the first element in the list - Easy
2. Delete the last element in the list - Easy
3. Delete the element at a position(numeric) - Easy
4. Delete the element with the given value - Easy
5. Delete a specific node - ***Not sure how to do this***

I guess the challenge I am facing is how to find the memory address of the node or how to pass the memory address of the node to the method.  The following is the code I have come up with. Obviously the **" def delete_node(self, node):"** does not work. The following is the code I have come up with so far.

```
from Node import Node


class SingleLinkedList:

"""Constructor. Sets the length of the linkedlist to zero and initializes head reference"""
def __init__(self):
    self.head = None
    self.length = 0

""" Method to get the length of the list """
def get_list_length(self):
    return self.length

""" Method to INSERT a node at the beginning of the list """
def insert_at_beginning(self, data):
    new_Node = Node()
    new_Node.set_data(data)

    if self.length == 0:
        self.head = new_Node
    else:
        new_Node.set_next(self.head)
        self.head = new_Node
    self.length += 1

""" Method to INSERT a node at the end of the list """
def insert_at_end(self, data):
    new_Node = Node()
    new_Node.set_data(data)

    if self.length == 0:
        self.head = new_Node
    else:
        current = self.head
        while current.has_next():
            current = current.get_next()
        current.set_next(new_Node)
    self.length += 1

""" Method to INSERT a node at the given position, i.e. after postion - 1 . Position count start at 0 """
def insert_at_position(self, position, data):
    if position > self.length or position < 0:
        return None
    else:
        if position == 0:
            self.insert_at_beginning(data)
        else:
            if position == self.length:
                self.insert_at_end(data)
            else:
                new_Node = Node()
                new_Node.set_data(data)
                current = self.head
                count = 0
                while count < (position - 1):
                    current = current.get_next()
                    count += 1
                new_Node.set_next(current.get_next())
                current.set_next(new_Node)
                self.length += 1

""" Method to INSERT a new node to the list. Default insertion at the end of the list """
def add(self, data):
    self.insert_at_end(data)

""" Method to PRINT the elements of the list """
def print_list(self):
    if self.length == 0:
        return "Linked List is empty"
    else:
        current = self.head
        while current.has_next():
            print str(current.get_data()) + " ---> ",
            current = current.get_next()
        print str(current.get_data())

""" Method to DELETE the node at the beginning of the list """
def delete_at_beginning(self):
    if self.length == 0:
        return "List is empty"
    else :
        self.head = self.head.get_Next()
        self.length -= 1

""" Method to DELETE the node at the end of the list """
def delete_at_end(self):
    if self.length == 0:
        return "List is empty"
    else:
        current = self.head
        previous = None
        while current.has_next():
            previous = current
            current = current.get_next()
        previous.set_Next(None)
        self.length -= 1

""" Method to DELETE a node at the given position, i.e. after postion - 1 . Position count start at 0 """
def delete_at_position(self, position):
    if position > self.length or position < 0:
        return "Position does not exist"
    else:
        if position == 0:
            self.delete_at_beginning()
        elif position == self.length:
            self.delete_at_end()
        else:
            count = 0
            current = self.head
            previous = None
            while count < position:
                previous = current
                current = current.get_next()
                count += 1
            previous.set_next(current.get_next())
            self.length -= 1

""" Method to DELETE a node with a given value """
def delete_value(self, value):
    if self.length == 0:
        print " List is empty "
    else:
        current = self.head
        previous = None
        while current.has_next():
            if current.get_data() == value:
                break
            previous = current
            current = current.get_next()
        if current.get_data() != value:
            print "Item " + str(value) + " not in the list"
        else:
            previous.set_next(current.get_next())
            self.length -= 1

def delete_node(self, node):
    if self.length == 0:
        print "List is empty"
    else:
        current = self.head
        previous = None
        found = False
        while not found:
            if current == node:
                found = True
            elif current is None:
                print "Node not in the list"
                return
            else:
                previous = current
                current = current.get_next()
        if previous is None:
            self.head = current.get_next()
        else:
            previous.set_next(current.get_next())
            self.length -= 1

def main():
    l = SingleLinkedList()
    print l.get_list_length()
    l.add(1)
    l.add(2)
    l.add(3)
    l.print_list()
    l.insert_at_beginning(500)
    l.insert_at_beginning(600)
    l.insert_at_beginning(700)
    l.print_list()
    l.insert_at_position(3, 99999)
    l.print_list()
    l.delete_at_position(3)
    l.print_list()
    l.delete_value(500)
    l.print_list()
    nd = Node()
    nd.set_data(2)
    l.delete_node(nd)
    l.print_list()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am following a book on Data Structures written in C++ and translating it to Python. I guess it is easy to pass the memory address in C++, maybe this is not doable using Python?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT:**
I have another challenge related to this class. I want to be able to find the length/size of the linked list both iteratively and recursively. Finding the length iteratively is straight-forward. How do I find the length recursively? I am able to visualize recursive approach in my head, but unable to code this in Python. Also, this is confusing as self is the first method in the parameter.

```
def sizeByIteration(self):
    current = self.head
    counter = 0
    while current is not None:
        counter += 1
        current = current.get_next()
    return counter

# def sizeByRecursion(self):
#     if self.head is None:
#         return 0
#     else:
#         self.head = self.head.get_next()
#         return 1 + self.sizeByRecursion()
```

Comment: for deleting at a position we can change the links, maintain two pointers, say `p1=head,p2=head.next` when p1 reaches the node you want to delete change `p1.next=p2.next`

Comment: The answer will have nothing to do with C++. Pythonic idioms are vastly different.

Comment: You mean the `l.delete_node(nd)` near the end of your test? That can't work in C++, either. The node simply isn't in the list, so it can't be deleted from it.

Comment: Your code should be equivalent to `delete_value(node.get_data())`. Forget memory addresses - you're  just deleting the value of the Node that's passed in

Comment: This operation is impossible even in C++ if there's no way to access the nodes of a list from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `is` instead of `==`. `is` will return `True` if two variables **reference** the same object. Whereas `==` will use a default comparator that compares the **value** of the objects.

Try this instead:

```
def delete_node(self, node):
    if self.length == 0:
        print "List is empty"
    else:
        current = self.head
        previous = None
        found = False
        while not found:
            if current is node:
                found = True
            elif current is None:
                print "Node not in the list"
                return
            else:
                previous = current
                current = current.get_next()
        if previous is None:
            self.head = current.get_next()
        else:
            previous.set_next(current.get_next())
            self.length -= 1
```

Also as a note: the benefit of python is that you can write very short, concise, and functional code. Take advantage of recursion if you understand the method. If you aren't at that point in university yet, don't worry about this and continue on your merry way.

Comment: Thanks, @Wesley Hoffman. On the note of recursion. I do understand what recursion is. Infact, I am stuch with one problem regarding recursion. I want to find the length/size of the linked list using iteration and recursion. Finding the size iteratively is straight forward, but I am not sure how to do this recursively as a class method in python. Can you help? 
    # def sizeByRecursion(self):
    #     if self.head is None:
    #         return 0
    #     else:
    #         self.head = self.head.get_next()
    #         return 1 + self.sizeByRecursion()

Comment: @ShivKonar I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5441339/5776539) might point you in a good direction!

Answer (score 0):

To call deleted_node() need to find node, that you can only do by traversing the list from head.

So instead of traversing twice, at first traversal itself we can delete node

Also, to find length by recursion
The logic written by you modifies the entire list, instead this will work

```
def sizeByRecursion(self, node):
    if node is None:
       return 0
    return self.sizeByRecursion(node.get_next()) + 1
```